# edit datagridview cells not working

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

i fill my datagridview, but now
i cant edit my data..

there is my code:

```
BindingSource b = new BindingSource();

string cus1 = getCustomers.getCustomersApi();
RootObject cus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(cus1);

dataGridView2.Columns.Clear();
AddCheckBoxForDataGridViewCustomer();
//  DataGridViewButtonColumn bc = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
// dataGridView2.Columns.Add(bc);

var result = cus.Rows.Select(r => new
    {
        CustomerId = r.CustomerId,
        Name = r.Name,
        Code = r.Code,
        Address = r.Address,
        PostalCode = r.PostalCode,
        City = r.City,
        Country = r.Country.Name,
        TaxNumber = r.TaxNumber,
    }).ToList();

// dataGridView2.DataSource = result;
// dataGridView2.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;

b.DataSource = result;
dataGridView2.DataSource = b;
dataGridView2.ReadOnly = false;
```

If i fill my data from database in the same datagridview, it works good..

```
dbConnect.connection.Open();
adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from " + dbConnect.tableCustomer + "", dbConnect.connection);
ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

you are binding grid to list of objects of anonymous type

but anonymous objects are immutable

binding works correctly and you can't edit values in cells

create class (say `CustomerGridModel`) with the same properties (not fields!) (`CustomerId`, `Name`, etc) and bind grid to `List<CustomerGridModel>`

```
BindingSource b = new BindingSource();

string cus1 = getCustomers.getCustomersApi();
RootObject cus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(cus1);

dataGridView2.Columns.Clear();
AddCheckBoxForDataGridViewCustomer();

var result = cus.Rows.Select(r => new
    CustomerGridModel
    {
        CustomerId = r.CustomerId,
        Name = r.Name,
        Code = r.Code,
        Address = r.Address,
        PostalCode = r.PostalCode,
        City = r.City,
        Country = r.Country.Name,
        TaxNumber = r.TaxNumber,
    }).ToList();

b.DataSource = result;
dataGridView2.DataSource = b;
dataGridView2.ReadOnly = false;
```

where `CustomerGridModel`:

```
public class CustomerGridModel
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name    { get; set; }
    // etc
    public string TaxNumber { get; set; }
}
```